# Python TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when trying to download a file

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server.py script that I run on Linux. And then I have a client.py script that I run on Windows. Once the client connects to the server, I want to get a file from the Windows machine to the Linux machine, by issuing the "grab*name_of_file.txt" command. But, when I try to grab the file, I get the following error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

This is my server.py code:

```
import socket
import os

def transfer(conn, command):
    conn.send(command)
    f = open('/tmp/test.png', 'wb')
    
    while True:
        bits = conn.recv(1024)
        
        if 'Unable to find out the file' in bits:
            print('[-] Unable to find out the file')
            break
        if bits.endswith('DONE'):
            print('[+] Transfer Completed.')
            f.close()
            break
        f.write(bits)

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("192.168.163.130", 8080))
    s.listen(1)
    print("[+] Listening for incoming TCP connection on port 8080")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("We got a connection from ", addr)

    while True:
        command = input("shell > ")
        if 'byeee' in command:
            conn.send(b'terminate')
            conn.close()
            break
        elif 'grab' in command:
            transfer(conn, command)
        else:
            conn.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
            out = conn.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            print(out)

def main():
    connect()

main()
```

This is my client.py code:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os

def transfer(s, path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        f = open(path, 'rb')
        packet = f.read(1024)
        
        while packet != '':
            s.send(packet)
            packet = f.read(1024)
        s.send('DONE')
        f.close()
    else:
        s.send('Unable to find out the file.')

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("192.168.163.130", 8080))
    
    while True:
        command = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if 'byeee' in command:
            s.close()
            break
        elif 'grab' in command:
            grab, path = command.split('*')
            #try:
            transfer(s, path)
            #except Exception, e:
            #   s.send(str(e))
            #   pass
        else:
            CMD = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            s.send(CMD.stdout.read())
            s.send(CMD.stderr.read())
            
def main():
    connect()
main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full traceback, not just the error itself.

Comment: s.send('DONE') ,you want to use s.send(b'DONE') ....and can you show which line error was occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network packet is just a collection of bytes without any specific encoding. That's why the method `send()` requires a byte array and not a string.

The error you get is just at the initialization stage, where you send the command `grab*<filename>` as a string in **server.py** at *line 5* with the command `conn.send(command)`. Replace it with `conn.send(command.encode('utf-8'))` as you already did in other parts of the code.

Hovewer, you have multiple points where the code would fail because you treat strings as byte arrays. Here the full files which work, except for a **TODO** you should solve.

server.py:

```py
import socket
import os

def transfer(conn, command):
    conn.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
    f = open('/tmp/test.png', 'wb')

    while True:
        bits = conn.recv(1024)

        print(bits)
        if b'Unable to find out the file' in bits:
            print('[-] Unable to find out the file')
            break
        if bits.endswith(b'DONE'):
            f.write(bits) #TODO:remove trailing DONE
            print('[+] Transfer Completed.')
            f.close()
            break
        f.write(bits)

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("localhost", 8080))
    s.listen(1)
    print("[+] Listening for incoming TCP connection on port 8080")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("We got a connection from ", addr)

    while True:
        command = input("shell > ")
        if 'byeee' in command:
            conn.send(b'terminate')
            conn.close()
            break
        elif 'grab' in command:
            transfer(conn, command)
        else:
            conn.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
            out = conn.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            print(out)

def main():
    connect()

main()
```

client.py:

```py
import socket
import subprocess
import os

def transfer(s, path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        f = open(path, 'rb')
        packet = f.read(1024)
    
        while packet != b'':
            s.send(packet)
            packet = f.read(1024)
        s.send(b'DONE')
        f.close()
    else:
        s.send('Unable to find out the file.')

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("localhost", 8080))
    
    while True:
        command = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if 'byeee' in command:
            s.close()
            break
        elif 'grab' in command:
            grab, path = command.split('*')
            transfer(s, path)
        else:
            CMD = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            s.send(CMD.stdout.read())
            s.send(CMD.stderr.read())
    
def main():
    connect()
main()
```

Comment: @Muj Zad People spend time to answer and help on stackoverflow. A thank you and an upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: HI @Pasquale, Thanks for the solution. It worked. Currently I am trying to figure out how to remove the 'DONE' from the end of the file.

Comment: I would go simply for `f.write(bits[:-4])`.